# Advantage of singular value decomposition of $X$ over eigenvalue analysis of $XX^T$

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Suppose I have a real $n \times N$ matrix $X$ where $n$ is a small number like $<20$ and $N$ is a big number like $>100000$. For example $X$ might be a time series of $n$ measurment quantities on a physical system, given for sample size $N$.

Then I might do a singular value decomposition on the data
$$X=U\Sigma V^T$$
where $\Sigma$ is diagonal and positive and the bases $U$ and $V$ orthonormal.

Or, alternatively, I might do an eigenvalue analysis on the covariance matrix (not normalized to the sample size $N$ here, for the sake of simplicity):
$$XX^T=U\Lambda U^T$$
where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and positive semi-definite and $U$ is orthonormal (orthogonal as a matrix). If $X$ is maximum rank ($=n$), we simply have
$$\Lambda=\Sigma^2$$
so both methods are basically equivalent. The only thing I miss with the eigenvalue analysis is the matrix $V$ on the "sample space", whereas I get all the necessary information in the "physical space" $U$.

To my understanding of the sources, one should avoid the eigenvalue analysis for two reasons:

1. as the square of $X$ has also squared condition number, the solution will be more sensitive to numerical round-off
2. first forming $XX^T$ requires more operations (I don't really understand this, see below)

While I just accept 1), I don't understand how an eigenvalue analysis on, say for my example figures above, a $(20\times 20)$ matrix (which has resulted from 400 inner products of $100000$ components) can be more expensive a computation than a singular value decomposition on a $(20\times 100000)$ matrix. I imagine that eigenvalue decomposition and singular value decomposition are each very expensive operations (if I understand Wikipedia correctly, they increase with the third power of the greater dimension), also because logical branches likely happen, causing cache misses on a computer. On the contrary, the inner products involved in $XX^T$ are trivial sequential operations.

So the benefit of the singular value decomposition not requiring the formation of the matrix product $XX^T$, should be far outweighed by the fact, that a $(20\times 100000)$ matrix is much bigger than a $(20\times 20)$ matrix, at least in my intuitive feel.

Is my intuition wrong for the example above? How could the advantage of SVD be justified intuitively?

What information would I draw from the matrix $V$ that is dropped for eigenvalue analysis in my case of a time series $X$? Is it a rotation in ... time (whatever that means)?

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, it's not clear how "time" is supposed to come into all this since you haven't told us what the rows and columns of your matrix $X$ represent

Comment: Many SVD algorithms (for instance, variants of the $QR$ method) actually do compute the matrix $XX^T$ and then apply an eigenvalue algorithm that takes advantage of the fact that $XX^T$ is symmetric and positive definite.  Applying a generic eigenvalue algorithm on $XX^T$ will be slower since such an algorithm is not designed to exploit this structure.

Comment: And indeed, once you computed $\Sigma$ and $U$, having $V$ isn't all that much of an advantage.  We could find $V$ from $U$ and $\Sigma$ by noting that the columns corresponding to non-zero singular values satisfy
$$
v_i = \frac 1{\sigma_i} X^Tu_i
$$ 
where $u_i,v_i$ are the $i$th columns of $U$ and $V$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Actually, I did say in my second sentence that $X$ be a time series in my example (I meant $N$ to be the indices of an equidistant time serires if that wasn't clear enough, but it doesn't matter). The reconstruction of $V$ is something I had forgotten indeed, thanks for the hint. As to eigenvalue algorithm, I'd take an eigenvalue algorithm for symmetric positive definite matrices for comparison, of course.

Comment: So I try to summarize: probably no real advantage for matrices $X$ that are 'that much rectangular' as in my example.

Comment: missed that about the time series, thanks. To the extent that I understand these algorithms I do think that there isn't all that much of an advantage to one approach vs. the other.  A caveat on that though: reviewing some old notes more closely, I now remember that the modern svd method effectively computes this eigendecomposition of $XX^T$ **without finding $XX^T$**.

Comment: The first step in a Golub-Kahan implementation is to apply left and right reflectors that bring $X$ into a bidiagonal form, so that the ensuing computation is also reduced to a square matrix of the smaller size, and there all operations lead to banded matrices of a small bandwidth.